# Handling messages between multiple apps

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I started using reactor and tried the multiple examples i found online, but i can not find anywhere some kind of example of messages between applications. I need to notify an application when a certain event happens in another application. Is it possible or did I missunderstood the project-reactor purpose?

Comment: jms might be able to help you out

Comment: Reactor can help you. But I think that other managed services which are cloud-based can be more helpful because they can promise consistency, reliability and more which your micro-service can't provide. Have a look at Kinesis in Amazon Web Services (AWS) or Azure/Google similar solutions. If it's a small app, consider using Kafka which provide the same solution and reactor have API for it. Enjoy!